# Fetch a Wikipedia article with Python

Tags: python, urllib2, user-agent, wikipedia, http-status-code-403

I try to fetch a Wikipedia article with Python's urllib:

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albert_Einstein&printable=yes")           
s = f.read()
f.close()
```

However instead of the html page I get the following response: Error - Wikimedia Foundation:

```
Request: GET http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albert_Einstein&printable=yes, from 192.35.17.11 via knsq1.knams.wikimedia.org (squid/2.6.STABLE21) to ()
Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED, errno [No Error] at Tue, 23 Sep 2008 09:09:08 GMT
```

Wikipedia seems to block request which are not from a standard browser.

Anybody know how to work around this?

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't block requests are not from a standard browser, it blocks requests that are from standard libraries without changing their user agent.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-urllib2.html) that superseedes [urllib](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-urllib.html) in the [python std library](http://docs.python.org/lib/) in order to change the user agent.

Straight from the [examples](http://web.archive.org/web/20070202031348/http://docs.python.org/lib/urllib2-examples.html)

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
infile = opener.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albert_Einstein&printable=yes')
page = infile.read()
```

Comment: Wikipedia attempts to block screen scrapers for a reason. Their servers have to do a lot of work to convert wikicode to HTML, when there are easier ways to get the article content. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Please_do_not_use_a_web_crawler

Comment: You shouldn't try to impersonate a browser by using a user agent like `Mozilla/5.0`. Instead, [you should use an informative user agent with some contact information](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).

Answer (score 37):

It is not a solution to the specific problem. But it might be intersting for you to use the mwclient library (http://botwiki.sno.cc/wiki/Python:Mwclient) instead. That would be so much easier. Especially since you will directly get the article contents which removes the need for you to parse the html.

I have used it myself for two projects, and it works very well.

Comment: Using third party libraries for what can easily be done with buildin libraries in a couple lines of code isn't good advice.

Comment: Since mwclient uses the mediawiki api it will require no parsing of the content. And I am guessing the original poster wants the content, and not the raw html with menus and all.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than trying to trick Wikipedia, you should consider using their [High-Level API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

Comment: Which will, in turn, still block requests from `urllib` using the library default user-agent header. So the OP will still have the very same problem, although the API may be an easier way to interface the wiki content, depending on what are the OP goals.

Comment: They work fine for me. Don't they work for you? Ex: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=info&titles=Main%20Page or http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Answer (score 3):

In case you are trying to access Wikipedia content (and don't need any specific information about the page itself), instead of using the api you should just call index.php with 'action=raw' in order to get the wikitext, like in:

'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?**action=raw**&title=Main_Page'

Or, if you want the HTML code, use 'action=render' like in:

'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?**action=render**&title=Main_Page'

You can also define a section to get just part of the content with something like 'section=3'.

You could then access it using the urllib2 module (as sugested in the chosen answer).
However, if you need information about the page itself (such as revisions), you'll be better using the mwclient as sugested above.

Refer to [MediaWiki's FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aFAQ#get_the_content_of_a_page_.28wikitext.29.3F) if you need more information.

Comment: hello if I do not know the section number as 3 but I know the section title to be 'Noun', how to get that particular section?

Answer (score 2):

The general solution I use for any site is to access the page using Firefox and, using an extension such as Firebug, record all details of the HTTP request including any cookies.

In your program (in this case in Python) you should try to send a HTTP request as similar as necessary to the one that worked from Firefox. This often includes setting the User-Agent, Referer and Cookie fields, but there may be others.

Answer (score 2):

[`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is awesome!

Here is how you can get the html content with `requests`:

```
import requests
html = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Albert_Einstein&printable=yes').text
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the user agent header you are sending in your request to something like:
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008072820 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/3.0.1 (Linux Mint)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to impersonate a browser user-agent; any user-agent at all will work, just not a blank one.

Comment: urllib and urllib2 both send a user agent

Comment: `s/blank/blank or default/` — the idea is exactly that you should somehow identify your bot through the user-agent header. That's why they block the `urllib` default one.

Answer (score 1):

Requesting the page with [`?printable=yes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein?printable=yes) gives you an entire relatively clean HTML document. [`?action=render`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein?action=render) gives you just the body HTML. Requesting to parse the page through the MediaWiki action API with [`action=parse`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Albert%20Einstein&formatversion=2) likewise gives you just the body HTML but would be good if you want finer control, [see parse API help](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse).

If you just want the page HTML so you can render it, it's faster and better is to use the new [RESTBase](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc) API, which returns a cached HTML representation of the page. In this case, https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/Albert_Einstein.

As of November 2015, you don't have to set your user-agent, but [it's strongly encouraged](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette#User-Agent_header). Also, nearly all Wikimedia wikis [require HTTPS](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2015/06/12/securing-wikimedia-sites-with-https/), so avoid a 301 redirect and make http**s** requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
s = urllib.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Albert_Einstein').read()
```

This seems to work for me without changing the user agent. Without the "action=raw" it does not work for me.