# Jquery crossdomain .load() div with id or class

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, html, cross-domain

My question is if there is anyway how i can load only a certain `div` like a text box from
an different domain

Like :

I want to load The webpage Spiegelonline but i only want the `.headline`.

It would be even better if i can load classes not just ID´s

I tried it like this

`<div id="asd"></div>`
`$('#asd').load('crossdomain.html #content');`

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to work.  From the [jQuery `.load()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

CORS is a possible alternative.  See [How can I load content from another site onto mine with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936288/how-can-i-load-content-from-another-site-onto-mine-with-javascript-jquery)