# Making a (hopefully simple) wiki parser with python

Tags: python, parsing, mediawiki, wikipedia

With the help of joksnet's programs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460921/extract-the-first-paragraph-from-a-wikipedia-article-python) I've managed to get plaintext Wikipedia articles that I'm looking for.

The text returned includes Wiki markup for the headings, so for example, the sections of the [Albert Einstein article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_einstein) are returned like this:

```
==Biography==

===Early life and education===
blah blah blah
```

What I'd really like to do is feed the retrieved text to a function and wrap all the top level sections in bold html tags and the second level sections in italics, like this:

```
<b>Biography</b>

<i>Early life and education</i>
blah blah blah
```

But I'm afraid I don't know how to even start, at least not without making the function dangerously naive. Do I need to use regular expressions?
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

PS Sorry if "parsing" is too strong a word for what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Why make yet another parser? Can't you just [get the HTML from the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) and alter/style the h2 and h3 tags with JavaScript/CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
def parseWikiTitles(x):
    counter = 1

    while '===' in x:
        if counter == 1:
            x = x.replace('===','<i>',1)
            counter = 2

        else:
            x = x.replace('===',r'</i>',1)
            counter = 1

    counter = 1

    while '==' in x:
        if counter == 1:
            x = x.replace('==','<b>',1)
            counter = 2

        else:
            x = x.replace('==',r'</b>',1)
            counter = 1


    x = x.replace('<b> ', '<b>', 50)
    x = x.replace(r' </b>', r'</b>', 50)
    x = x.replace('<i> ', '<i>', 50)
    x = x.replace(r' </i>', r'<i>', 50)

    return x
```

I pass the string of text with wiki titles to that function and it returns the same text with the == and === replaced with bold and italics HTML tags. The last thing removes spaces before and after titles, for example `== title ==` gets converted to `<b>title</b>` instead of `<b> title </b>`

Has worked without problem so far.

Thanks for the help guys,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way here would be to let MediaWiki take care of the parsing. I don't know the library you're using, but basically this is the difference between

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Albert%20Einstein&rvprop=content

which returns the raw wikitext and

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Albert%20Einstein&rvprop=content&rvparse

which returns the parsed HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I may end up doing that but I've already tried recovering HTML and it gave me unicode encoding errors I didn't know how to fix. Plus converting the HTML to plaintext wasn't that straightforward either. Maybe I'll try making a parser that just goes through the text and replaces every first === with <i> and every second with </i>, then goes through it again and replaces every == with <b> and every second with </b>. Problem is if the count ever gets off it'll break, but I guess it should work in most situations...

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and scraping modules like Scrapy and Beautifulsoup to parse and scrape wiki pages.
Now that you clarified your question I suggest you use the py-wikimarkup module that is hosted on github. The link is https://github.com/dcramer/py-wikimarkup/ . I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for. I have already gotten the pages in almost exactly the format I want them. I just want to replace the `==Heading 1==` and `===Heading 2===` with `<b>Heading 1</b>` and `<i>Heading 2</i>`. I don't think Beautifulsoup or Scrapy can help me with that.