# Unresolved import yaml in python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, 64-bit, yaml, pyyaml

I have searched for similar problem but I could not find a solution.

I have installed pyyaml in my windows machine from this link:
http://pyyaml.org/download/pyyaml/PyYAML-3.10.win32-py2.7.exe

I have a python 2.7 installed. I can't import yaml into my python module (using eclipse with pydev).

my library locations in pydev preferences are also updated and checked. I am very new to yaml and I just want to implement a program i found here that uses yaml.

Here is the program I am trying to run:
http://pastebin.com/FVDxLWNG
courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/users/408564/joksnet

Context: [Extract the first paragraph from a Wikipedia article (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460921/extract-the-first-paragraph-from-a-wikipedia-article-python)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had two instances of python installed 2.7.6 and 3.4. 
I was using the 3.4 for coding and yaml was installed into the the other one switching the code base in the IDE solved the issue.