# why can't I use urllib2.urlopen for wikipedia site?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, wikipedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetch a Wikipedia article with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120061/fetch-a-wikipedia-article-with-python)

```
>>> print urllib2.urlopen('http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AF%9B%E6%B3%BD%E4%B8%9C').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: check their (robots.txt)[http://zh.wikipedia.org/robots.txt] page to see whether the bot you're using is banned

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide a user-agent [else you'll get a 403](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API#Identifying_your_client), like you did.

> On Wikimedia wikis, if you don't supply a User-Agent header, or you
>   supply an empty or generic one, your request will fail with an HTTP
>   403 error. [See our User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy). Other MediaWiki installations
>   may have similar policies.

So just add a user-agent to your code and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the page with `wget` of `cURL`.
If you can't then you might have a network problem.
If you can, then Wikipedia might block certain user agents. In that case, use urllib2's [add_header](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.add_header) to define a custom user agent (to imitate a browser request).

Comment: don't need to imitate a browser request, can just use a custom user agent. I got results while using the user agent 'elssar-at-elssar-laptop'.