# Parsing Wikipedia recursively and fetch text from included links

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, web-scraping, wikipedia

Because I hate clicking forth and back reading through Wikipedia articles I am trying to build a tool to create "expanded Wikipedia articles" according to the following algorithm:

- Create two variables: `Depth` and `Length`.
- Set a Wikipedia article as a seed page
- Parse through this article: Whenever there is a link to another article fetch the first `Length` sentences and include it in the original article (e.g. in brackets or otherwise highlighted).
- Do this recursively up to a certain `Depth`, i.e. not deeper than two levels.

The result would be an article that could be read in one go without always clicking to and fro...

How would you build such a mechanism in Python? Which libraries should be used (are there any for such tasks)? Are there any helpful tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) for requesting the url. For parsing the htmlpage there is  wonderful library for you called [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). One thing you need to consider is that while scanning Wikipedia with your crawler you need to add a header alongwith your request. Or else Wikipedia will simply dissallow to be crawled.

```
 request = urllib2.Request(page)
```

adding header

```
 request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686)')
```

and then load the page and give it to `BeautifulSoup`.

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response)  
 text = soup.get_text()
```

this will give you the links in a page

```
 for url in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):  
       link = url['href']
```

And now regarding the algorithm for crawling Wikipedia what you want is something called [Depth Limited Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-limited_search). A pseudocode is provided in the same page which is easy to follow.

And other functionality of the said libraries can be googled and are easy to follow. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for this - it's a bit higher-level than urllib and other built-in libraries. In particular, it's easy to navigate around just like you're using a browser, with commands like `follow_link()` and `back()`.

To get the lines you want, have a look at the sources of a few Wikipedia pages to see where the summary starts in the HTML page - from a quick browse, I think you want to find the div with id "mw-content-text" and get the text from the first `<p>` element. As others have mentioned, [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) would be good at this.

Alternatively, you could try one of the Python libraries that work with Wikipedia - there's a list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCreating_a_bot#Python, and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120113/607861) [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460921/extract-the-first-paragraph-from-a-wikipedia-article-python) in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api) stackoverflow answers.

Sounds like a fun little project, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to parse the html pages. Use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to get the nested pages. You may need to use a few regular expressions to massage or evaluate the extracted links.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the html or you could parse the raw version looking for `[[Link]]`. 
Either way, you should talk a look at:

[urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html?highlight=urllib#urllib) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/intro/#philosophy)

Answer (score 1):

use the wikipedia python library which lets you see the links on the pages including the links in the "see also" section and you can iterate through them and use the library to get the content on them.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia