# network unavailable from python script

Tags: python, url, ip, urllib2

I tried to access wikipedia page from python

```
a = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser")
```

this caused an error

```
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

So I tried

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "MyBrowser"})
a = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Still I get the same error

**Now I am unable to view wikipedia in chrome or firefox**..It says 'chrome cannot find the page'

But if I type in the wikipedia url in an anonymous proxy ,the page is displayed without any problem

What do you think is the problem?Is my IP blocked? I checked firewall(in ubuntu lucid)

```
sudo ufw status

Status: inactive
```

I also tried

```
sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

can somebody please help?

Comment: Looks like you had lost internet. What did `ping google.com` produce?

Comment: I wouldn't scrape Wikipedia like that. Just use their API: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: @pydesigner, ping shows network is ok  `64 bytes from bom04s01-in-f6.1e100.net (173.194.36.6): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=116 ms
64 bytes from bom04s01-in-f6.1e100.net (173.194.36.6): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=149 ms...`

Comment: I highly recommend using their API rather than scraping. If I had to guess, its probably a user-agent header, along with a combination of other things. But seriously, their API is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible Wikipedia is blocking it?
Running your supplied code raises an Exception:

`urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

It seems possible that Wikipedia might be blocking (simple) programmatic access to push people to use their API.

See [Fetch a Wikipedia article with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120061/fetch-a-wikipedia-article-with-python) for more discussion about this problem.

Comment: I am wondering why it didn't work, since I am supplying a header to pass it as a browser

Answer (score 1):

Are you using proxy? If you are using proxy, try to add following lines to your code:

```
import urllib2
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'user:password@your_proxy_server:proxy_port'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
```

Answer (score 1):

because your headers is not right ,use this to have a try :

```
import  urllib2
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1'}
req = urllib2.Request("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser", headers=headers)
a = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print a.read()
```

hope you good luck !

Comment: still getting the same error..Are you sure about the header? I think you can pass any name as User-Agent

Comment: it is probable that there is something wrong with your network configuration,or you have been blocked by wiki

Comment: or you can ping en.wikipedia.org to check if there is something wrong

Comment: after waiting for 15 minutes got `64 bytes from wikipedia-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org (208.80.154.225): icmp_seq=465 ttl=51 time=368 ms
64 bytes from wikipedia-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org (208.80.154.225): icmp_seq=466 ttl=52 time=373 ms`

Comment: well the "block" seems to have gone away now..I can see wiki pages in browser